# Problemas con tablas de multiplicar en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo unas tablas de multiplicar tengo hecha ya una con `for` peor ocupo hacer con `while` y `do while` pero no me sale el mismo resultado la de `for` es esta

```
<?php

for($t=8; $t<=10; $t++)
{

 echo "<h3> Tabla del $t </h3>";
 // generamos la tabla
 for($i=8; $i<=12; $i++)
 {
  echo "$t x $i = ".($t*$i) . "<br/>";
 }
}

?>
```

Con `while` peor ya no sale lo mismo

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

```
<?php
$t=8;
$i=8;
while($t<=10){
    echo "<h3> Tabla del $t </h3>";
    $t++;
    while($i<=12){
        echo "$t x $i = ".($t*$i) . "<br/>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

¿Cuál puede ser mi error?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Reemplaza el echo "$t x $i" con comillas simples por si son reemplazados por los valores reales de las variables y además pon que es lo que esperas encontrar y que es lo que te devolvió

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos errores puntuales en su código

- El incremento de `$t` debería ser después del segundo `while` si no iniciaría desde `9`
- La variable `$i` después del segundo `while` queda en 13 , entonces debería reiniciar su valor a `8` si no ya no volvería a entrar al ciclo del segundo `while`

  ```
  $t=8;
  $i=8;
  while($t<=10){
     echo "<h3> Tabla del $t </h3>";
     while($i<=12){
        echo "$t x $i = ".($t*$i) . "<br/>";
        $i++;
     }
   $i=8; //Reset variable
   $t++; //Incremento
  }
  ```

Comment: si gracias asu es como decias ahoira interare hacerlo con un do while

Answer (score 1):

tenes un error de lógica al aplicar el `while`.

Por cada vuelta del `for`, lo primero que hace es inicializar la variable contador y después empieza a iterar..

O sea que internamente, el `for` hace algo asi:

```
$i=8;
```

Tu segundo `while`, no lo hace. La primera vez i tiene el valor correcto, pero despues nunca vuelves al valor de origen, y allí esta el error.

Debes mover la instrucción:

```
$i=8;
```

Antes de

```
while($i<=12){
```

y se resolvera tu problema.